# Error 500 on log out? saml2 itfoxtec-identity-saml2, Okta_SAML_Example

Tags: .net-core, saml, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am testing a project Okta_SAML_Example by nickgamb here: https://github.com/nickgamb/Okta_SAML_Example/tree/master/Pages

I know that it is using the ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 package to implement SAML. I have intergrated the app with ADFS. However, when I sign out, I get an Error 500.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Single logout with AD FS is supported and I have used it multible times.

It is hard to say what cause the 500 error. It is probably a configuration error.

I need more error details to help you further.